# Rotate x-axis label in vega heatmap?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have built a heat map of correlation matrix
[image]

1. How can I rotate the x-axis label
2. Is it possible to make the legend vertical like
   [image]

I tried

```
"axes": [
      {
        "orient": "bottom", 
        "scale": "x", 
        "labelAngle": -45,
        "tickOffset": 0,
        "labelAlign": "right",
        "domain": false,
        "title": "Features"
      },
      {
        "orient": "left", 
        "scale": "y", 
        "domain": false,
        "title": "Features"
      }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "orient": "right", 
      "direction" : "vertical",
      "fill": "color",
      "type": "gradient",
      "title": "Correlation",
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titlePadding": 4,
      "gradientLength": {"signal": "height - 16"}
    }
  ],
```

but not happening

i am using vega "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json" schema

Answer (score 2):

Rotating the x-axis names, this worked

```
      {
        "orient": "bottom", 
        "scale": "x", 
        "labelOverlap":false,
        "domain": false,
        "title": "Features",
        "encode": {
          "labels": {
            "update": {
              "angle": {"value": -50},
              "fontSize": {"value": 10},
              "align": {"value": "right"}
            }
          }
        }  
      },
```

[image]